# Node-red split text and store variable

Tags: node-red

Using node-red, I receive messages from Telegram which are formatted like:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "chatId": 12345,
    "messageId": 1,
    "type": "message",
    "content": "Hi_._MainChat"
  },
  "originalMessage": {
    "message_id": 1,
    "from": {
      "id": 1234567890,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "John",
      "username": "JohnDoe",
      "language_code": "en"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 12345,
      "first_name": "John",
      "username": "JohnDoe",
      "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1590504750,
    "text": "Hi_._MainChat"
  },
  "_msgid": "3be22fdd.3c9f5"
}
```

I want to **split** the `content` at '`_._`' and store the left ("*Hi*") and the right ("*MainChat*") part in two variables for later use. Could one be so kind and assist me how to do this?

I tried a function like

```
// Split the message content to extract text and origin
var text = {};
text.payload = (msg.originalMessage.text.split("_._"))[0];
text.type = "text";

var origin = {};
origin.payload = (msg.originalMessage.text.split("_._"))[1];
origin.type = "origin";

msg.payload.text = text.payload;
msg.payload.origin = origin.payload;

return [text,origin];
```

but failed miserably.

Comment: Please expand on "but failed miserably". what output do you get with the code you have provided.

Comment: Your sample code worked fine for me. All I did was change your return statement to `return msg;` and a debug node showed the expected result: `{text: "Hi", origin: "MainChat"}`